# ttest for categorical variable

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test, p-value

I want to perform a test to compare education level of living people and education level of death people. I got the data of education level for living people from the census of 2010. The data of education level for death people from the CDC. The data looks like this...

### Living people education level

```
+-----------------------------------+
| GROUP        | TOTAL_COUNT | MEAN |
+-----------------------------------+
| 11-          | 28587748    | 13.7 |
+-----------------------------------+
| Just 12      | 58440600    | 28.0 |
+-----------------------------------+
| Some College | 61206147    | 29.1 |
+-----------------------------------+
| Bachelor+    | 60821634    | 29.3 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

### Death people education level

```
+----------------------------------------+
| GROUP        | TOTAL_COUNT | MEAN      |
+----------------------------------------+
| 11-          | 624934      | 32.887178 |
+----------------------------------------+
| Just 12      | 784319      | 41.274821 |
+----------------------------------------+
| Some College | 256255      | 13.485430 |
+----------------------------------------+
| Bachelor+    | 234728      | 12.352571 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I want to find out the significant difference (t-test, ANOVA, etc) between similar groups. For instance; the significant difference between Group 11- of living people and Group 11- of death people. I thought about a t-test or ANOVA but since my values are counts I can't calculate the standard deviation because is not one.
What test I can perform to find out how significant is the difference between GROUP 11- of living people and 11- of death people. I want to perform the test for each group.
I'm utilizing jupyter notebook.

Comment: What is the education of "death people"? Do you mean the educational achievement of people who died last year, or something like that?

Comment: I got the death data from the CDC dataset. I create a subset of the data by counting the people with specific education level. The column 11- are people with 11th grade or less. Just 12 is people with just high school diploma. With this line of code I count people by education level... `edu_count = pd.DataFrame(pd.value_counts(edu_data.Education))`. After that I group them as you can see in the table above.

Comment: what is 'mean' ? The name of variable it represents ! and procedure adopted for computing it.

Comment: MEAN is the average isn't? Remember total_count is counting people, therefore for 11- would be 28587748 / 209,056,129 = .137 where 209,056,129 is the sum of the total_count column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to run multiple two-samples proportion test.

To compare `11-` for both samples, you can run the proportion test with 0.137 and 0.32887. Your sample sizes will be all the living people and all the dead people.

> http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx?Tutorial=AP

However, I believe the tests will give you significance results at both 10% and 1% significance level because you have very large samples.

Comment: Seems like proportion test is my solution. Do you know if `scipy` has a function to perform the test or I have to create the function myself?

Comment: @Gilbert http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/_modules/statsmodels/stats/proportion.html